# Find a version of Cplex for large data

Tags: version, cplex, opl

I try the BM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio/Version: 22.1.1.0/Build id: Community Edition for my thesis, but the data is too large for it.
My data have 52 columns and 676 rows, after running, I got "Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded" and it asked me to buy another version. However, its too costly for 1 time use.
So now, anyone hepl me to find a free version that i can download and run my data?

I also forgot my student IBM ID password (I ask for send an email to my mail but get nothing).

Answer (score 0):

As you can read at

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer

You could either use the Free Academic Initiative Cplex version or run Cplex in the Cloud with Free Credit